# How i display result From search use Whoosh?

Tags: python, lucene, information-retrieval, whoosh

I have some example:

```
 Example : Query = "we present"
    Result:
    0 By encoding the rich knowledge that is present in text, these representations are able to capture many aspects of word meaning.
    1 In this paper, we present a dependency graph-tostring grammar based on a graph grammar, which we call edge replacement grammar.
    2 We present a sentence rewriting method that generates more monotonic translations to improve the speedaccuracy tradeoff.
```

I want display 2th sentence - "we present .....tradeoff" is first. And I'd ask : Why I search phrase "we present" but the result showed two sentence not consist of phrase "we present". This is my code :

```
def search_Document(fileIndex, Query):
# phrase_query = '"'+Query.lower()+'"'
phrase_query = Query
ix = index.open_dir(fileIndex)
with ix.searcher(weighting=scoring.Frequency()) as searcher:
    # qp = QueryParser("sentence_analyse", schema=ix.schema)
    pharse_qp = MultifieldParser(["sentence", "title"], schema=ix.schema)
    phrase_q = pharse_qp.parse(phrase_query)
    q = pharse_qp.parse(Query)
    results = searcher.search(phrase_q,sortedby='rank',limit=30)
    for i,result in enumerate(results):
        print(i,result['sentence'])
if __name__ == '__main__':
   search_Document('IndexDirectory','"we present"')
```